# Problem separating the repository into two independent projects on git

Tags: django, git, kivy

I made a mistake at the starting of a project, and that was to write a kivy project and the backend written with django rest in a same folder and repository (meaning the required libraries are both in the same venv too) and now that I want to deploy Django project I do not know how to separate these two projects (which includes libraries) and I do not see any solution.

For example, is it possible to create two separate branches for it? And if so, how? And how do I manage and distribute the requirements.txt libraries?(Because the number of libraries is very large and about 200 libraries and the project size is huge.

I do not know if more explanation is needed but I am very confused and really need help. Thankful

Comment: How you want to restructure is really up to you. There are pro and cons for having everything in one venv and one repo. If you want to separate them I would suggest to put them in different folders on the top level, then have their own requirements.txt in their folders etc. But if those projects are developed and deployed separately, it would make even more sense to put them in different repos in my opinion.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken Do you think it will be useful to use the orphan branch? Or is it enough to divide them into two simple branches? (However, due to the size and complexity of the projects, dividing libraries manually into two requirements.txt will be difficult for me.)

Comment: Careful. If you are talking about branches in git, those are not meant to hold different projects, but e.g. to work on new features for the same project.

Comment: If you want to keep everything in one repo, but have different virtual environments just move all related files in different subfolders. git should be able to figure out those files are just moved.

Comment: One more thing if I may. If you are developing those two parts together locally it may be beneficial to keep them in the same virtual environment locally, but put them in their own repos with their own requirements.txt / setup.py configs. You can then use tox to test that the dependencies are correct. That is how my setup usually looks when developing several django apps together.

Comment: Here is an example how the project structure looks. Under the root folder you have one venv, one django project folder and then one folder for each django app (with each being their repo). All on the same level. https://allianceauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/development/dev_setup/aa-dev-setup-wsl-vsc-v2.html#setup-dev-folder-on-wsl